# What bower package should I use for AngularUI /UI Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bower-install

I have been working on an angular site and I leveraged [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) to construct many of the controls. (I manually downloaded and referenced **ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.1.2.min.js** in my project.

Everything was working well until I tried to transition to bower to manage client side packages. To do this I went to: [the code on Github](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap). On that page it says:

> **Install with NPM**
>   $ npm install angular-ui-bootstrap
>   
>   **Install with Bower**
>   $ bower install angular-bootstrap

Directly below this is the statement:

> Note: do not install 'angular-ui-bootstrap'. A separate repository - **bootstrap-bower** - hosts the compiled javascript file and bower.json.

If I look at the package **bootstrap-bower** package it appears to be ***just*** bootstrap and there no angular directives declared at all.

From this I concluded that **angular-bootstrap** is the correct package to install. After installing and referencing the package everything is working properly ***except for the accordion controls***.

I'm confused... Did I install the wrong package or is there a dependency issue?

Answer (score 0):

When I researched this I found that the package installed by bower the accordion controller was declared like this:

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.accordion', ['ui.bootstrap.collapse'])

.constant('accordionConfig', {
  closeOthers: true
})

.controller('AccordionController', 
['$scope', '$attrs', 'accordionConfig', 
function($scope, $attrs, accordionConfig) {
  // This array keeps track of the accordion groups
  this.groups = [];

...
```

But in the manually downloaded version declared the accordion it was declared like this (Notice the **uib** prefix):

```js
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.accordion', ['ui.bootstrap.collapse'])

.constant('uibbAccordionConfig', {
  closeOthers: true
})

.controller('UibAccordionController', 
  ['$scope', '$attrs', 'uibAccordionConfig', 
  function($scope, $attrs, accordionConfig) {
  // This array keeps track of the accordion groups
  this.groups = [];

...
```

Digging further in I found that the problem was that the installed package was 0.13.4 and the manually downloaded version was 1.1.2. This is because "Manage Bower Packages" in Visual Studio only lists up through 0.13.4 in the GUI. I had to manually edit the version in the bower.json file and then everything worked correctly.